# Constructing a semigroup from a small category

Tags: category-theory, terminology, semigroups, monoid

The [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/474/12490) was given as an example for a semigroup without an identity:

> Finite sets of matrices of varying dimensions, where the product $A*B=\{PQ \mid P \in A, Q \in B \text{ and } dim(Q)=codim(P)\}$, where $dim$ and $codim$ are the dimensions of the source and the target spaces of a matrix.

Editor clarification: $dim(Q)$ is actually the dimension of the target space of the matrix $Q$, $codim(P)$ is the dimension of the source space of the matrix $P$ in the citation.

It took me some seconds before I understood what is meant by that example. And then I thought that this construction could be applied to any small category, not just matrices.

So for a small category $C$, let $S_C:=\{M\subset\operatorname{hom}(C):|M|<\infty \}$ and for $A,B\in S_C$ define $A*B:=\{f\circ g:f\in A, g\in B,\operatorname{source}(f)=\operatorname{target}(g)\}$. Then $S_C$ together with the operation $*$ is a semigroup. (The identity would be $E=\{\operatorname{id}_A:A\in\operatorname{ob}(C)\}$. If the category $C$ has only a finite number of objects, we have $E\in S_C$.)

What I find even more interesting is that $S_c:=\{A\in S_C:|A|\leq1\}$ is a sub-semigroup of $S_C$. Because $S_c=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\{f\}:f\in\operatorname{hom}(C)\}$, we have a "natural" correspondence between the semigroup $S_c$ and $\operatorname{hom}(C)\cup\{0\}$. Here $0\notin\operatorname{hom}(C)$ is an absorbing element corresponding to the empty set $\varnothing\in S_c$. The semigroup operation of $S_c$ is just the composition of the corresponding morphisms if this is defined, or the empty set otherwise.

Given that this construction was extracted from an answer to a question about interesting semigroups, it can't be totally unknown. However, I would like to know whether this construction has a special name, where it is described, and whether it has  "interesting" applications.

Comment: Where you say «without an obvious identity element» you can in fact write «without an identity element»: the empty set is a zero, so there is no identity element (unless there are no objects in the category...)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well, I guess I found out now what the identity element looks like, if it exists: $\{\operatorname{id}_A:A\in \operatorname{ob}(C)\}$. So for a category with a finite number of objects, $S_C$ has an identity. And for a category with just one object, even $S_c$ has an identity. And even in the general case, the semigroup $S_C$ is the sub-semigroup of an "obvious" monoid.  So the statement "without an obvious identity element" is false, at least in the sense which I had in mind.

Comment: Dear Thomas, the point of my comment above is that except in the silly situation in which the category C does not have any object at all, your semigroup does *not* have an identity element.

Comment: My memory here is unreliable, but I think I've seen a construction like this in a recent Banach-algebras paper, where the authors take a small category and define some kind of convolution algebra associated to it. However, that is almost certainly not the first occurrence of the construction, even if my memory is correct

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I tried to explain the identity element now, and fixed the terminology related to the zero/absorbing element. Note that the existence of an absorbing element doesn't contradict the existence of an identity. So I still believe that $S_c$ has an identity element if the category $C$ has only one object, and that $S_C$ has an identity element if the category $C$ has only a finite number of objects.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel, an absorbing element $A$ and an identity element $I$ can only coexist if they are equal: $A\cdot I=A$ because $I$ is an identity, but $A\cdot I=A$ because $A$ is absorbing. Now, if an identity element is also absorbing, there can only be *one* element. Now, if $C$ is not the empty category, then $S_c$ and $S_C$ have *at least* two elements.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I'm not sure what you are getting at. It is certainly possible to have semigroups with an identity element and a zero element; $\{0,1\}$ with multiplication is the obvious example.